# How to attach mysql_insert_id in a file upload?

Tags: php

how do we attach mysql_insert_id() in a file uploads so that each file gets unique name ? I did try the following code but didn't work. please advice. Yhanks

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$dest = trim($uploaddir. $id. basename($_FILES['photo']['name']));
```

Comment: Define "didn't work". Make test outputs of  `$id` (is there anything in there?) and `$dest` (is it a valid path?)

Comment: Make sure you handle the case when mysql_insert_id() returns FALSE instead of an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be

```
if(false !== ($id = mysql_insert_id())
{
    $dest = sprintf("%s%d_%s",$uploaddir,$id,trim(basename($_FILES['photo']['name']));
    if(!file_exists($dest))
    {
        //move_uploaded_file
    }else
    {
        //You cant program :(
    }
}else
{
    //DB Error.
}
```

You should write your code so you add the file to the directory before you add to database.

- Get the data from `$_FILES`
- Sanitize the data and validate the file `Size,Ext,Headers,Name`
- Make sure the file does not already exists
- Generate a `UniqueID` and create a hash from a static string, Example `1`
- Store the file on the server and verify its move ok
- Add meta data to the database along with the unique ID and file location
- Bobs your uncle.

Example 1:

```
define('FILE_NAME_SALT','MySecret$alt');

$uid = md5(rand(0,100) . $uid . FILE_NAME_SALT . $FileName);
```

Store file like `HASH.ext`

Comment: And underneath "//You cant program :(" is a routine that sends you an SMS informing you of the fact that since that block of code ran, you need to switch professions.

Comment: i did use getimagesize() and $dest = trim($uploaddir. rand(5,15000). uniqid(). basename($_FILES['photo']['name'])); I am not sure how safe is this. I am really confused with mysql_insert_id(), do I need to query and get this id or this id is just attached upon insertion ?

Comment: just attach upon insert would be fine, as long as you have a link of some kind attaching the file location to the database row it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem that you can take some steps to solve yourself before asking.  For starters, print out $id.  Is it a valid Id?  Or is it FALSE (it might be).  Then echo out $uploaddir, $_FILES['photo']['name'], and basename($_FILES['photo']['name']).  Finally, echo out $dest.  I'd be rather surprised if you don't catch the mistake by doing these simple debugging exercises.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hashing function to do this. For example, md5 or sha1 are good choices for unique filenames. You could use a filename that the md5() function returns given the file's initial name.

Comment: mysql_insert_id() is guaranteed to be unique assuming he's only dealing with 1 table.  I would personally do what you recommend.  But it's ok the way it is.